# Execute a command for each entry in a file

Tags: shell

How can I execute a command for file which has address of jar files. The command that I want to execute is `jar xf entry.jar`.
I d like to execute that command and sent the outputs to another file.

Assume my file contains following entries.

```
a.jar
b.jar
c.jar
```

What I want is simply extract these jar files and sent the output to another file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess what you want is something like this:

```
xargs -n1 -d'\n' jar xf <list
```

Where `list` is the name of the file containing entries.

I'm not sure what you mean by send the outputs to another file. If you want a record of what the `jar` command prints on the console you can append a `>out.log` argument at the end.

(The `-d` option is there in the case filenames contains spaces and are listed one per line.)

Comment: I tried following command but it didnt work. xargs jar xf < out_file > output2.log. It print "xargs: Could not exec command: No such file or directory"

Comment: Make sure that `jar` is installed on your system.

Comment: Does not work for me too. I have jar on my system. It silently does nothing.

Comment: The shell part is correct, the `jar`'s syntax is wrong – its first parameter after the command has to be the .jar file's name: `xargs -n1 -d'\n' jar xf entry.jar <list`.

Comment: manatwork: As I understood it, the provided list contains “.jar” filenames, not paths to be extracted from a single jar.

Comment: Seems I misunderstood the problem. Then [version 2](http://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/29217/2) works for me. (Not the original one, regardless the absence of spaces in the file names.)

Comment: Yes `-n1` is essential as `jar` only accepts one archive as argument. Unfortunately my first version had been tested on a singleton list :-/

Comment: Thanks for your replies guys. manatwork: actually you did understand my problem. yes I have path on my files. And these path are adress of jar files. Sory if I explained it poorly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
for entry in $(<list) ; do jar -xf "$entry"; done > output2.log
```

works for you?

```
jar -xf a b [...]
```

would try to extract b from a, but you want to extract all 3 jars, as far as I can see.

Comment: What if a filename contain a space?

Comment: More importantly, I missed the dollar sign! :) Yes, jar-files, containing spaces, are pretty rare, and it will not work that way. And if the filenames contain linefeeds, too.